# How to use an expression as flag argument

Tags: bash, parameters, flags

Lets say I have

```
tmp0=2
let tmp=2*$tmp0+3  #randomm example
```

I can write `$(cat something | cut -d " " -f$tmp)`,
but what I want to know is how to write `$(cat something | cut -d " " -f$(2*$tmp0+3))`

Basically I want to know how use "mathematical expression" as a flag parameter

Comment: Do you really want the `$( )` around the whole thing? That's going to try to execute the output as a command (unless it's just part of a larger command, in which case the output'll become part of that larger command).

Answer (score 1):

You are actually pretty close:

```
$(cat something | cut -d " " -f$((2*tmp0+3)))
```

Note the `((` and `))`.  That is how it is done. Also, take notice that I didn't need the `$` on the variable.  Inside a mathematical expression, variables don't need `$` and it acts a lot more like C.  To get the value out of it, you do need the `$` on the front of `((`.  If you don't need the value, but just the behavior, you can leave off the `$`.  Here is another example of this:

```
for ((i=0; i < 10; ++i)); do
    echo $i
done
```

Since I didn't need the value out of the expression, I can leave out the `$`.